# How to get object rect/coordinates from VNClassificationObservation

Tags: ios, swift, image-recognition, ios11, coreml

have an issue with getting from `VNClassificationObservation`.

My goal id to recognize the object and display popup with the object name, I'm able to get name but I can't get object coordinates or frame.

Here is code:

```
let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: requestOptions)
do {
    try handler.perform([classificationRequest, detectFaceRequest])
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Then I handle

```
func handleClassification(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
      guard let observations = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] else {
          fatalError("unexpected result type from VNCoreMLRequest")
      }

    // Filter observation
    let filteredOservations = observations[0...10].filter({ $0.confidence > 0.1 })

    // Update UI
   DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in

    for  observation in filteredOservations {
            print("observation: ",observation.identifier)
            //HERE: I need to display popup with observation name
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATED:

```
lazy var classificationRequest: VNCoreMLRequest = {

    // Load the ML model through its generated class and create a Vision request for it.
    do {
        let model = try VNCoreMLModel(for: Inceptionv3().model)
        let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model, completionHandler: self.handleClassification)
        request.imageCropAndScaleOption = VNImageCropAndScaleOptionCenterCrop
        return request
    } catch {
        fatalError("can't load Vision ML model: \(error)")
    }
}()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because classifiers do not return objects coordinates or frames. A classifier only gives a probability distribution over a list of categories.

What model are you using here?

Comment: I use Inceptionv3().model and it looks I am not able to get coordinates.

Comment: That's because Inception-v3 does not give you coordinates, only a dictionary of class names and the probabilities for these classes.

Answer (score 12):

A pure classifier model can only answer "what is this a picture of?", not detect and locate objects in the picture. All the [free models on the Apple developer site](https://developer.apple.com/machine-learning) (including Inception v3) are of this kind.

When Vision works with such a model, it identifies the model as a classifier based on the outputs declared in the MLModel file, and returns `VNClassificationObservation` objects as output.

If you find or create a model that's trained to both identify and locate objects, you can still use it with Vision. When you convert that model to Core ML format, the MLModel file will describe multiple outputs. When Vision works with a model that has multiple outputs, it returns an array of `VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation` objects — one for each output of the model.

How the model declares its outputs would determine which feature values represent what. A model that reports a classification and a bounding box could output a string and four doubles, or a string and a multi array, etc.

Addendum: Here's a model that works on iOS 11 and returns `VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation`: [TinyYOLO](https://coreml.store/tinyyolo)

Comment: Can you suggest a particular model that provides VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation results?

Answer (score 0):

For tracking and identifying objects, you’ll have to create your own model using Darknet. I have struggled the same problem, and used TuriCreate to train model, and instead of just providing images to the framework, you’ll have also to provide ones with bounding boxes. Apple have documented here, how to create those models:
[Apple TuriCreate docs](https://apple.github.io/turicreate/docs/userguide/object_detection/)